# ClEnqueueCopyBuffer with offset 1

Tags: c, opencl, offset

To optimize a kernel i need to make a copy of a cl_mem object with an offset.

```
count_buffer3[n] = count_buffer[n+1]
```

is the desired result

Looking at the specification of ClEnqueueCopyBuffer it seems to be possible with a simple argument.

```
cl_int clEnqueueCopyBuffer (    cl_command_queue command_queue,
    cl_mem src_buffer,
    cl_mem dst_buffer,
    size_t src_offset,
    size_t dst_offset,
    size_t cb,
    cl_uint num_events_in_wait_list,
    const cl_event *event_wait_list,
    cl_event *event)
```

My idea was to set dst_offset to 1. So copy_buffer[0] goes to copy_buffer[1]
In my case the command looks like:

```
    clEnqueueCopyBuffer(command_queue, count_buffer, count_buffer3, 1, 0, (inCount1 + 1) * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

So i want to copy count_buffer to count_buffer3 with an offset of 1.
The result should be like this:

```
count_buffer[1] = 2
count_buffer[2] = 12
count_buffer[3] = 26

count_buffer3[1] = 12
count_buffer3[2] = 26
```

Unfortunately, if my dst_offset is 1 like shown in the example my complete count_buffer3 object contains only "0" as int values.

If my offset is 0, the copy works fine and both count_buffers are identical.

Additional Information:
Here are the init of the clmem objects:

```
cl_mem count_buffer3 = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, (inCount1 + 1) * sizeof(int), NULL, &err); errWrapper("create Buffer", err);

cl_mem count_buffer = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, (inCount1+1) * sizeof(int), NULL, &err); errWrapper("create Buffer", err);
```

I am using INtel INDE update 2 with visual Studio 2013

Am i doing sth wrong here, or should the copy with offset work like this?

Edit:
i reduced the buffer size by one and the result changes.
Instead of all "0" i get some very huge numbers.

example from debug:

```
count_buffer[0] = 0
count_buffer[1] = 31
count_buffer[2] = 31

count_buffer3[0] = 520093696
count_buffer3[1] = 520093696
count_buffer3[2] = 520093696
```

It is an improvement to "0" values, but still wrong.
any ideas?

Thanks for the answer so far!

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, `520093696 = 31 << 24;` Witch is exactly equivalent to reading 8 bits out of offset in a 32bit int array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset is in bytes. You probably want an offset of `sizeof count_buffer[0]` and a size of `(n - 1) * sizeof count_buffer[0]`:

```
clEnqueueCopyBuffer(
    command_queue, count_buffer, count_buffer3, 
    sizeof(cl_int), 0, 
    inCount1 * sizeof(cl_int), 
    NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot! i didnt consider the size of offset. i should better read the documentation more precisely.

Comment: @KäptnFreiversuch Just FWIW, there's no place where you specify the size of a single element, so the function cannot possibly behave like you expected it would, regardless of documentation :)

Answer (score 2):

It's very likely `clEnqueueCopyBuffer` returns an error which you don't check. According to the [manual](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueCopyBuffer.html):

> CL_INVALID_VALUE is returned if src_offset, dst_offset, cb, src_offset + cb, or dst_offset + cb require accessing elements outside the buffer memory objects.

which seems to be your case.
You probably want to pass size to copy one less than the size of your buffer:

```
clEnqueueCopyBuffer(command_queue, count_buffer, count_buffer3, 1, 0, inCount1 * sizeof(int), NULL, NULL, NULL);
                                                                      ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: You were correct about the Buffersize. I Reduced it by one. Ill add details in the question